# Dealing With Simultaneous Collisions in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, collision, bounds

I am creating a 2d game in which a player can collide with enemy ships. Currently when the player hits the enemy ship the enemy ship is removed. Another feature I am struggling with is that when two enemy ships hit the player simultaneously the player should be removed. Is there anyway of doing this?

Below I have my Collision class that handles the collisions between the player and the enemy

```
    // if enemy runs into player will return true
public static boolean Collision (EntityEnemy enemyShips, EntityPlayer entP ) {

        if (enemyShips.getBounds().intersects(entP.getBounds())) {
            return true;
        }

    return false;

}

// returning two enemies colliding with the player 
public static boolean doubleCollision (EntityEnemy enemyShips, EntityPlayer entP ) {

        if (enemyShips.getBounds().intersects(entP.getBounds())) {
            count ++;

            if (count == 2) {
                return true;
            }
    }


    return false;
}
```

Comment: pseudo-code: `for(EntityEnemy enemy : enemies) { if (isCollision(...)) collisions.add(enemy); } if (collisions.size() >= 2) player.remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Thinkin in a game based on turns. When an enemy hits the player and the thread responsible for analising the game status run, it will know every ship intersection so you can see every ship which the player have intersections. My tip is:

Instead of using a single validation to verify if the ship was intersected, return the list of all ships with intersections. This way you can remove all of them no matter how many collisions you've got.